# Make svg fill div even after rotation

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I've got an inline svg with `viewBox={ "0 0 150 345" }`.
I want to be able in rotate it with 90, 180, 270 degrees (where the rotation origin is the center of the svg), and that the svg will take the entire space of the container in any position.

Currently I have:

```
<svg
  style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
  viewBox={ "0 0 150 345" }
  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
>
    <g transform={ "rotate(90 75.5 172.5" }>
        // some content
    </g>
</svg>
```

Problem is, when the rotation is with 90 or 270 degrees, the svg doesn't scale based on the width, rather still based on the height.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried removing "width", and keeping the "height: 100%;" and then adding "display: block;"?

Comment: Doubtful if you can. Transforms are **purely** visual and do not affect other layout. You'd probably have to adjust the viewbox with JS...but that sounds pretty complex.